# NodeJS&Glob: возможен ли единый паттерн для исключения произвольных комбинаций файлов и расширений?

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

### Уточнение вопроса всвязи с отрицательными голосами

Данное glob-выражение позволяет выбрать все `.pug` файлы, кроме index.pug ([песочница](https://globster.xyz/?q=%2Fsrc%2F!(index)%7B.pug%2C.haml%2Cindex.haml%7D&f=%2Fsrc%2Findex.pug%2C%2Fsrc%2Findex.haml%2C%2Fsrc%2Fabout.pug%2C%2Fsrc%2Fabout.haml)):

```
/src/!(index){.pug,.haml,index.haml}
```

Теперь предположим, что расширение `haml` нас больше не интересует, а потому всё, что с ним связано, надо убрать. Вопрос: как можно сократить приведённое выше выражение, **в корне не меняя его струкрутру**? Это условие важно для создания простого, и в то же время гибкого алгоритма генерации glob-выборок.

Неверное решение (никакие `.pug` файлы не будут выбраны):

```
/src/!(index){.pug}
```

Решение

```
/src/!(index).pug
```

не подходит потому, что в будущем мы можем захотеть добавить поддержку других расширений (например, `.slim`), и тогда код генерации приведённой выше glob-выборки придётся в корне менять.

Решение

```
/src/!(index).+(pug|slim)
```

также не подходит потому, что из него мы не можем исключать произвольные файлы. Что, если мы захотим исключить `index.pug` и `about.slim`, а `index.slim` и `about.pug` - оставить?

Другими словами, все приведённые выше решения не масштабируемые на произвольное количество:
* имён файлов, которые должны быть выбраны
* расширений имён файлов, которые должны быть выбраны
* конкретных файлов (т. е. комбинации имени файла и расширения), исключаемых из выборки файлов.

**Важный момент**
В данном вопросе мы не рассматриваем **получение файлов** с помощью `glob`, `globby`, `gulp.src()` и так далее. Здесь рассматривается генерация конкретной строки, а что мы с этой строкой дальше будет делать - не имеет отношения в этому вопросу.

И ещё: если данную задачу невозможно решить в одну строку, так и напишите (только пожалуйста, добавьте объяснение или комментарий).

---

### Исходный вопрос

В вопросе [NodeJS&Glob: exclude arbitrary files with arbitrary filename extensions from glob selections in one string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54230615/nodejsglob-exclude-arbitrary-files-with-arbitrary-filename-extensions-from-glo/54233104#54233104) ("Исключение произвольных файлов с произвольными расширениями в одном glob-выражении) я добивался того, чтобы файл `index.pug` был исключён из выборки pug- и haml- файлов `src\\markup\\!(index).+(pug|haml)`, при этом `index.haml` должен остаться. Было предложено [такое решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54233104/4818123):

```
/markup/!(*index){.pug,.haml,index.haml}
```

Честно говоря, не понимаю, зачем здесь `*`, работает из без неё. Так или иначе, решение работат хорошо, но ввиду того, что данное glob-выражение планируется генерировать программно, **решение должно масштабироваться на любые комбинации имён файлов и расширений имён файлов** включая исключение одного файла с одним расширением. В данном вопросе я хочу исключить из выборки .pug-файлов только `index.pug`, но при этом решение должно легко масштабироваться на любое количесто исключаемых имён файлов и расширений.

Без приведённого выше требования, наиболее простым решением было бы `/markup/!(index).pug`. Но тогда при масштабировании придётся добавлять проверку на количество имён файлов:

```
if (filenameExtensionThatMustBeExcludedIsOnlyOne) {
    // генерируем....
    return /*...*/`/markup/!(index).pug`
} 
// предполагается, что массив файлов, которые должны быть включены, извесен
return /*...*/`/markup/!(index){.pug,.haml,index.haml}`
```

Но можно ли решить задачу без условного выражения c паттерном типа `/*...*/markup/!(filename1, filename2, ..., filenameN){ .targetExtension1, .targetExtension2, mustBeKept.targetExtension1}`?

К сожалению, решение `/markup/!(index){.pug}` (масштабированный `/markup/!(*index){.pug, .haml, index.haml}`) не приносит желамого результата.